# HTML / CSS - Image link only working on half the image

Tags: html, css

I have an image thumbnail with text that is on the right side of the image. I have a hyperlink on the image that pops up the full size image.

Now the hyper link only works on the bottom half the image, (underneath where the text is inline to the image).

Oddly enough, it seems to work fine on jsfiddle, but not on the website.

Is there anything that could be causing this problem? The JSFIDDLE below is exactly how it is on the website.

http://jsfiddle.net/EJvm2/1/

**CSS:**

```
    .content {
        width: 500px;
        padding: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .content img, .content h3 {
        float: left;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:5px;
    }
    .content img {
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
    .content p {
        padding: 40px 0 0 20px;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="content"> <a id="image1" href="images/site_images/acorn-award.jpg" title="image title.">
            <img src="images/site_images/thumb.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="120" />
        </a>

    <p>This is some text explaining the image</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Removing the text altogether allows the entire image to be clickable.

Comment: JSFiddle works fine...

Comment: I mentioned that it works fine in the jsfiddle, but not in the website.

Comment: how are we supposed to find the error, if you don't post the code actually containing the error? Actually, if you would, probably you would find the error for yourself...

Comment: I don't expect anyone to tell me the error, but like Jim has done, he has helped me find the error. Since I have no idea which part of the code is the problem. I hoped by describing the problem, someone would help me where to look and it worked.

Comment: @Christoph I guess that making a _code book_ (yes, code that makes your scroll looks like having `height: 1px`) doesn't help anyone... But yes, you're right.

Comment: try setting your `<a>` tag with id=image1 to `float:left`. 

`#image1 {float:left;}`

Comment: First step: Try to put up an isolated !minimal! test where the problem occurs. If by doing so you still can't spot the problem, ask for help. As long as you haven't tried this, it's of not much use asking others. Perhaps they might fix your problem, but probably you haven't learned anything and next time you will run into trouble again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is something elsewhere on the page that is overlaying part of the link.  You can find out what it is by right-clicking on the part that doesn't work and selecting "Inspect element" or its equivalent in whichever browser you are using.

Comment: But removing the text for some reason allows the entire image to be clickable. Really doesn't make sense.

Comment: You're right. The text paragraph is overlapping the image. Although the text doesn't. I'll try re size the paragraph

Comment: Try the regular fixes, clear cache, reload etc, could just be a browser issue more than code.

Comment: @user3012826 why u don't you modify the z-index for the image.

Comment: Adding "position:inherit;" to the ".content p" class fixed the problem, previously it was set to relative.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason for the following declaration:

```
.content img, .content h3 {
    float: left;
}
```

Randomly (at least it makes no sense in the fiddle *on the img element*) floating elements almost always causes problems. In your case most likely the image size does not fit the containing element, thus causing overflow and overlapping issues. Remove the float (move it to the containing anchor) or at least clear it.

Comment: It has since been removed.